# Weird crash log related to CALayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, crash, calayer

I encountered today a weird bug with an app I'm working on.
The problem was with a catalog module. Above each page, there was a small black area, since the page didn't fill 100% the screen. Tapping on that zone would generate a crash.

My crash log looks something like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x2fd00fec
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   QuartzCore                      0x35d812ac CA::Transaction::ensure_compat() + 0
1   QuartzCore                      0x35da2648 CALayerMapGeometry_(CALayer*, CALayer*, void (*)(void*, CA::Mat4<double> const&), void (*)(void*, CA::Mat4<double> const&), void*) + 28
2   QuartzCore                      0x35da25f8 -[CALayer convertPoint:fromLayer:] + 52
3   UIKit                           0x32457018 -[UIView(Geometry) convertPoint:fromView:] + 68
4   UIKit                           0x32456d40 -[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:] + 172
5   UIKit                           0x32456d50 -[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:] + 188
(...)repeat the line above^ until it reached 511
511 UIKit                           0x32456d50 -[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:] + 188
```

Even more, xcode ends up crashing soon after.
The debug navigator shows me something even more weird: http://i43.tinypic.com/5txnq0.png and then continued with a HUGE list of , like here: http://i41.tinypic.com/2h81ctw.png

I don't really know where to begin with...
The catalog module is old and well tested, and something like this never happened before. 
I know there are many variables and things that might affect the app, but if anyone could shed even a tiny bit of light on this, I would be really grateful
As I said, I don't even know how to start approaching this matter, it doesn't look like your regular "accessing a deallocated object", "memory leak" or other problems I encountered so far

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion somewhere. Did you override `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]` somewhere? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: An infinite recursion might be more a more precise description of what's going wrong here, but yes, I've seen this exact behavior when overriding things the wrong way. Make sure you didn't use a `[self something]` when you needed a `[super something]`.

Comment: Yea, recursion is more proper...fixed.

Comment: Nope, "hitTest:withEvent" isn't used anywhere in the app, but I do have a few instances of CALayer that I need to check. An infinite recursion does sound plausible, I'll check first all the iterations in the app. Thanks for the sugestions, guys!

Comment: @BBog, Did you find what was the issue? I know that it is a crash related to recursion. But, what is causing the recursion. I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Suran unfortunately it's been so long since then and I forgot. What I do remember is that I tried to rewrite all the offending code

Comment: @BBog Well, I too couldn't find the reason for the recursion and ended up re-writing the code. No more crashes now. :-)